# In Rails5.1.4 calling POST request give no route matches [GET] error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a SubscriptionSignupsController

```
 def create
   @subscription = SubscriptionSignup.new(subscription_params)
   if @subscription.save
     redirect_to @subscription
   else
     render 'new'
   end
 end
```

My routes.rb file contains

```
resources 'subscription_signups', only: [:create, :new]
```

when I'm calling `localhost:3000/subscription_signups` I get

> No route matches [GET] error

My view for new.hmtl.erb file we are using gazelle design systems as sass

```
<div class="SubscriptionSignup">
<div class="SubscriptionSignup-content">
    <form class="simple_form Form Form--protectSubmit">
            <div class="email-signup">
            <%= simple_form_for @subscription, html: { class: "Form Form--protectSubmit" } do |f| %>
                <div class="dr-FormField Form-inputWrapper">
                    <div class="gds-FormField-label">

                            <%= f.input :email, placeholder: "Email address"%>
                                    <%= f.input :password, placeholder: "6 Characters Minimum"%>
                                    <%= f.input :password_confirmation, placeholder: "Same as Password"%>
                                <%= f.input :name%>
                                <%= f.input :address_lane_1%>
                                <%= f.input :address_lane_2%>
                                <%= f.input :city%>
                                <div class="Form-InputGroup">

                                                <%= f.label :state %>
                                                <%= select_tag "state", options_for_select(us_states)%>


                                        <%= f.input :zip%>

                                </div>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>



                <%= f.button :submit, "Review Order", class: "gds-Button Form-button" %>

            <% end %>

        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: What's the output for `rake routes` ?

Comment: subscription_signups POST   /subscription_signups(.:format)                                          subscription_signups#create
new_subscription_signup GET    /subscription_signups/new(.:format)                                      subscription_signups#new

Comment: Btw if you call `.create` on your SubscriptionSignup model, you will already save the instance there and the latter if-block doesn't have much point. You should rather replace the initialization to something like `@subscription = SubscriptionSignup.new(subscription_params)`

Comment: I actual code is      
@subscription = SubscriptionSignup.new(subscription_params) 
Sorry for the wrong info over there but I'm not able to solve the issue

Comment: remove `only: [:create, :new]` or add to `:index` and `:show` to the list and then localhost:3000/subscription_signups will work

Comment: How are you submitting the form contents? Can you share the form header and the submit button code?

Comment: <div class="SubscriptionSignup">
    <div class="SubscriptionSignup-content">
        <form class="simple_form Form Form--protectSubmit">
            <h2 class="Form-title gds-Heading gds-Heading--secondary">Monthly Subscription</h2>
                <div class="email-signup">
                <%= simple_form_for @subscription, html: { class: "Form Form--protectSubmit" } do |f| %>
submit button code
<div class="Form-actions">
                    <%= f.button :submit, "Review Order", class: "gds-Button Form-button" %>
                    </div>

Answer (score 1):

If `@subscription.save` is successful, then your **#create** action will redirect to **#show** but you aren't defining the **show** action in your routes. You have 2 options (assuming the error is due to the #create action redirect to #show:

1. Add the missing **show** route to routes.rb like this: `resources 'subscription_signups', only: [:create, :new, :show]`
2. Redirect the flow to somewhere else than `redirect_to @subscription` (the missing **show** route)

Have a look at [Rails routing documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions) for more info.

Comment: I'm not able to create[POST request], when doing localhost:3000/subscription_signups/new I'm rendering a new form when I fill in the details and click the review button it render the new form again but I wont create

Comment: In that case it looks like the #create action flow ends up in the `else` block where #new is re-rendered. I think you might have some validation errors or problems with your `subscription_params` method. What does the log say about it?

Comment: My validation in SubscriptonSignup model

class SubscriptionSignup < ApplicationRecord
    before_save {self.email = email.downcase}

    VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
    validates :email, presence: true, length: {maximum: 100}, format: {with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX}
    validates :name, presence: true
    validates :address_lane_1, presence: true
    validates :city, presence: true
    validates :state, presence: true
    validates :zip, presence: true
    has_secure_password
    validates :password, presence: true, length: {minimum: 6}
end

Comment: I ment the instance you are saving - if you add `Rails.logger.debug("DEBUG: SUBSCRIPTION VALID? #{@subscription.valid?}")` right before the if-block in #create action and then search the same debug-message in your server log, then is the `@subscription` instance valid?

Comment: will it effect the app if we use @subscription on 2 different controllers?

Comment: Unlikely, I believe you have some validation errors still (under that I mean that the object saved in `@subscription` is invalid. To make sure it is/it's not the problem, I need to see the `@subscription.valid?` output in server log or `@subscription.errors` output. If your run your server locally then you should see the "DEBUG... " message I described earlier.

Comment: for some reason my create action is not being called. when I put the Rails.logger in create I am not able to see the debug information.

Comment: In that case I believe the problem resides in the form view. Could you please edit your question with the full simple-form part from your view-file?

Comment: I added the view can you take a look at it

Answer (score 0):

If you are using simple_form_for then you should be able to do something like this

url_for(:action => 'create', :controller => 'subscription'),
    :method => 'post' do |f| %>

I hope that this helps you out

Comment: Im using simple_form_for in my views, its throwing me an error

Comment: @ManojParitala I just made a update, I hope that this helps

Comment: The site is going to index but not create action

Comment: it's trowing 
    wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 1..2) 
error